# React Forms - Input Pattern Validation is lost when I click the Submit Button with OnClick()

Tags: forms, reactjs

My form validation is defined in my input fields. They are 'required' and they have a 'pattern'. When I click my submit button, it correctly tells me if any fields are invalid. However, I need my button to actually do something. So when I add an onClick={this.someFunction}, suddenly all my form validation is completely lost and it submits my request regardless. How do I fix this?

```
  saveTicket=(event)=>{
event.preventDefault();
this.setState({submit:1})
```

}

```
          <form>
        <input required className="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Event Name" defaultValue={this.state.name} onChange={this.updateName}/>
        <input required className="form-control" id="date" pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" defaultValue={this.state.date} onChange={this.updateDate} placeholder="Date (YYYY-MM-DD)"/>
        <input required className="form-control" id="seat" defaultValue={this.state.seat} onChange={this.updateSeat} placeholder="Seat"/>
        <br/><label>Price in TikTik Coins</label><input type="number" min="1" pattern="\d+" defaultValue={this.state.pprice} className="form-control" id="seat" onChange={this.updatePPrice} placeholder="Sale Price"/>
        <label>Max Resale Price in TikTik Coins</label>
        <input required className="form-control" id="pprice" type="number" min="1" pattern="\d+" defaultValue={this.state.sprice} onChange={this.updateSprice} placeholder="Max Resale Price"/>
        <i>This ticket can never be sold above the Max Resale Price.</i>
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick={this.saveTicket}>Create Ticket</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning the `saveTicket` function to the `onSubmit` event on the form instead of assigning it directly to the button, so it doesn't override the submit event necessary to validate the HTML5 attributes you are using (`pattern`, `required`):

```
<form onSubmit={this.saveTicket}>
  <input required ... etc />
  <input required ... etc />
  <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Create Ticket</button>
<form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I find forms very tedious in React =/